# How to mock method with any arguments?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I write following row in my test:

```
 when(Product.fromNode(any(Node.class), any(Locale.class),anyString())).thenReturn(productMock);
```

I see following error message:

> you cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing

It is impposible because I can't use `any` at this case. But I don't know what concrete argument will be passed to the method but I know that I should handle it same.

What can you advice for me ?

Comment: Hi, 

It looks like you're doing a call to a static method Product? This needs to be a mocked object.

Comment: @David Billings yes, I know

Comment: @Jens java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method fromNode(Node, Locale, String) in the type Product is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I used  `PowerMockito.mockStatic`
but I used RunWith annotation different than:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```